# Unable to use font css file in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs(Nextjs),Whenever i am trying to use "css" in project then i am getting following error in my screen

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0'
```

How can i solve this ?
Here is my code in _app.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../styles/css/style.css'
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
```

Comment: You cannot add links like that

Answer (score 0):

The lines with  :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
```

should be inserted in index.html. And you should use css from cdn

ex:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: if i want to create separate page then ? i mean if i have to create "about" page then again i have to add all these css files ?

Comment: You can use react styleSheet : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/
or something like styledComponent : https://styled-components.com/docs/basics